# Is there any way to match the body of a match statement with a Rust macro?

Tags: macros, rust

I have something like this in mind:

```
macro_rules! mymatch {
   ($obj:ident, ($matcher:tt => $result:tt),*) => {
       match $obj {
           $matcher
       },
   }
}

mymatch! {
    x,
    10 => "Ten",
    n if n < 5 => "Less than 5"
}
```

I don't want to reimplement the `match` statement, but I do want to put additional stuff on either side. However, I can't work out how to match
the contents of a match statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There a few things wrong with your syntax. If you want to match a repeated pattern then you need to start the grouping with a `$`, like this: `$($matcher:tt => $result:tt),*`.

Next, you'll likely want to match more than identifiers, since any expression is valid to match against, so change that to `expr`. Left of the `=>` you will want a `pat` (pattern), not a `tt`. A token tree is general, but for example, in `n if n < 5` will match 5 separate tokens - `n`, `if`, `n`, `<`, `5` - and you generally only fall back on that when nothing else works. The same for result - this should be an `expr` (expression) too.

Ignoring the `if < 5` guard for now, you can match the following:

```
my_match! {
    x,
    10 => "Ten",
    _ => "something else"
}
```

with the following macro:

```
macro_rules! my_match {
   ($obj:expr, $($matcher:pat => $result:expr),*) => {
       match $obj {
           $($matcher => $result),*
       }
   }
}
```

The guards are annoying because they are optional, but the `?` quantifier is not yet stable. Instead you have to use `*` (0 or more), even though it will technically match more than you need it to.

The full macro is then:

```
macro_rules! my_match {
   ($obj:expr, $($matcher:pat $(if $pred:expr)* => $result:expr),*) => {
       match $obj {
           $($matcher $(if $pred)* => $result),*
       }
   }
}
```

And supports the this usage:

```
let x = 7;
let s = my_match! {
    x,
    10 => "Ten",
    n if x < 5 => "Less than 5",
    _ => "something else"
};
println!("s = {:?}", s); // "Something else"
```

A block is also an `expr`, so this is also valid:

```
my_match! { 
    x,
    10 => "Ten",
    n if x < 5 => { 
        println!("it was {}", n); 
        "Less than 5" 
    },
    _ => "something else"
};
```

Comment: That's a lot of matching just for something that I am going to put back in the same order again! Ah, well, I have seen this before with rust macros. Many thanks!

Comment: Just note that this isn't 1-to-1 mapping of Rust's `match` statement. This requires a comma after block (`match x { None => {} _ => () }` is not valid), and disallows a trailing comma